# Reading a CSV file into Mplus

Tags: dataset

I am using Remote Desktop Client 2.1.1 on my Mac to connect to an Windows application server that serves up Mplus 6.12. Then I run the following script:

```
Title:      Loading data from CSV and performing GMM
DATA:       FILE IS "\\tsclient\Macint1 on Mike's Macbook\Users\Aron\Downloads\output.csv";
VARIABLE:   NAMES ARE repo_name t03 t04 t05 t06 t07 t08 t09 t10 t11 t12;
            CLASSES = c (2);
ANALYSIS:   TYPE = MIXTURE;
            STARTS = 40 8;
MODEL:      %OVERALL$%
            i s | t03@0 t04@1 t05@2 t06@3 t07@4 t08@5 t09@6 t10@7 t11@8 t12@9;
OUTPUT:     TECH1 TECH8;
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
*** ERROR
  The number of observations is 0.  Check your data and format statement.
  Data file:  \\tsclient\macint1\users\mike\github\local\latent_growth_classes\output.csv
*** ERROR
  Non-missing blank found in data file at record #1, field #: 1
```

I have tried specifying the path in multiple ways, as well as providing the CSV file with and without headers, but I always get the same message. What am I doing wrong? How do I read the CSV file into Mplus?

Comment: I know this is a data management question, but it is very specific to a statistical tool (Mplus), therefore I think the chance of getting an answer on Stackoverflow is lower than stats.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first row of a data file in Mplus has to be the first line of data, so NO variable names above! Hence it has to look like this.

```
9.00,3.00,1.00,1.00,34.00,35.00 
0.00,9.00,2.00,1.00,44.00,41.00 
  .    .    .    .     .     .
  .    .    .    .     .     .
  .    .    .    .     .     .
0.00,4.00,3.00,1.00,44.00,33.00 
1.00,4.00,3.00,2.00,36.00,37.00
```

Therefore you have to define the names with the `Names ARE` statement and it is important that you "remember" the exact order of the variables (as you cannot retrieve them from your data file). To get a .csv file without headings you have to open the .csv file with TextPad (or something similar) and delete the the row of variables and save the file again.

Note: If you are smart... Use cut instead of delete and paste this line of variables in Mplus, in this way mistakes are much less likely!